# 'index' is defined but never used. Error mesage, does anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I have been following a YouTube tutorial on how to make a crud application and I have typed the code word for word carefully.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9zM2UmavZA

I keep getting this error showing:

Failed to compile.

./src/views/Dashboard.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\Home\testdb\src\views\Dashboard.vue
7:44  error  'index' is defined but never used  vue/no-unused-vars

Previously I had a similar error but was able to fix it by adding: // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars above the line of code when:
const doc = await blockerCollection.add(data) and doc is delcared but its vlaue is never read.

This scenario is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0YxR.png)

```
<div class="dashboard">
        <h1>Hi, {{ userProfile.name }}</h1>
        <BlockerForm />
        <v-row>
            
            <v-col md="4" v-for="(blocker, index) in blockers" :key="blocker.id">
                <v-card>
                    <v-img
                        v-if="blocker.image"
                        height="250"
                        :src="blocker.image"
                        lazy-src="https://via.placeholder.com/250"
                    >
                    </v-img>
                    <v-card-title>{{ blocker.title }}</v-card-title>
                    <v-card-text>
                        <p class="subtitle-1">Name: {{ blocker.username }}</p>
                        <p class="subtitle-1">Urgency: {{ blocker.urgency }}</p>
                        <p>{{ blocker.description }}</p>
                    </v-card-text>
                    <v-card-actions>
                        <v-btn color="red">Delete</v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </div>
```

Index is defined but never used in this case and shows the error:

```
[vue/no-unused-vars]
'index' is defined but never used.eslint-plugin-vue
```

I tried adding the // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars above it but the line doesn't turn green and I don't understand how to fix it. I have looked at some other posts on how to turn it off but i hasn't worked.

```
rules: {
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "off"
```

When setting up the project on command prompt I may have clicked on Linter by accident, do you think if i didnt click on it, that these issues would be occuring?

I'm new to coding and trying to figure this out so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, You can just solve the issue by removing the index from the code. Update the v-for to `v-for="blocker in blockers"`.

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you the error disappered

Comment: Maybe this can help `<div v-for="(bubble, index) in bubbles" :key="index"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the index from the code as you are not using it and hence it's not needed.
Update the v-for to v-for="blocker in blockers"